# Javascript, DOM: img position always registers as 0,0

Tags: javascript, dom

In javascript I get the position of an img element like this:

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
img_position = rect.top +","+rect.left; 
alert(img_position );
```

Most of the time this works, but I also get some images that always say 0,0 as the position, regardless of where they are. Why is this? How can I get the actual position?

One example is here http://www.kraftrecipes.com/recipes/pork-chops-apples-stuffing-111258.aspx

for the advertising image with

```
src = "http://s1.adformdsp.net/Banners/2421967/2421967.jpg"
```

EDIT: Argh, reloading the page again again made the problem go away. Same code. Maybe some banner ad that is not being shown again. I'll update this if I see the issue again. (But maybe someone out there has seen this before?)

Comment: Are you certain you have the right element?  If I open the console and type `jQuery("#ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_e3811a74_ee9d_49d3_96cd_8f74fb23564d_ctl01_ucGWSRecipeTools11_ucGWSRecipeLogo_imgPromoImage")[0].getBoundingClientRect()` I get an object with non-zero top and left attributes.  Are you checking these before the element is put in the DOM/before the image is loaded? I can think of lots of ways this might be failing.

Comment: You're right. The one that fails has src = http://s1.adformdsp.net/Banners/2421967/2421967.jpg. And now even that one doesn't appear anymore.